# Cron Job Not working

Tags: shell-script, cron

I have been trying to create a `cron` job to execute a script located in `~/Documents/script.sh` at midnight every night and every 8 hours after that.

I have found a lot of material on this but for some it doesn't work.

This is what I have:

```
* 0 * * * ~/Documents/script.sh
0 */8 * * * ~/Documents/script.sh
```

Comment: Please show what you've done, starting with the output of `crontab -l`

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Thanks, I have included what I have so far. Cannot figure out what is the issue.

Comment: by the way this is one of the sources I used:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562804/running-cron-job-on-linux-every-6-hours

Comment: Before analysing the script, please check /var/log/cron and see whether the cron is even trying to run the script. If you use environment variables in the script, it script may give errors while run from cron.

Comment: Try putting the full path to the scripts in crontab entries, not `~`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no tilde expansion in your cron job, you have to put in something like:

```
0 */8 * * * /home/yourloginname/Documents/script.sh
```

This will run `script.sh` (assuming it is executable (`chmod +x script.sh`)), at midnight, 8 AM and  4 PM.

Leave out the first line you indicated, that would run the script every minute between midnight and 1 AM.